# Is CouchDB-Lucene still the best way to integrate Lucene or SOLR into a CouchDB database?

Tags: solr, nosql, lucene, couchdb

I am currently working on integrating an indexed text search into a couch database. In the past, for a previous project with the same requirements, we used couchdb-lucene, to integrate lucene into couch.

However, it looks like couchdb-lucene hasn't been receiving active development anymore since lucene split back into lucene and solr, as well as couch promising some upgrades to their built in mango search.

I am not an expert with any of the software, and haven't been keeping up with the tech as it progresses too well, but I was wondering if people were moving over largely to SOLR, or whether most people are sticking with couchdb-lucene

The specific project that requires the implementation of lucene is an index wide search to return documents that fit a variety of parameters put in by the user on a search page, and return relevant documents. Originally couchdb-lucene was used because it allowed us to search for things that fit 5-10 different requirements into a single query, instead of requiring us to build unique views for each search or doing multiple queries and cross referencing.

I've looked around at various sources and forums about the topics, but most discussion about the software is years old at this point, going back a decade, which makes me further worried that people have moved on to different software.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like CouchDB-Lucene was discontinued. The github repository was archived by his owner in april/2023.

Now he is collaborating to the project Clouseau (https://github.com/cloudant-labs/clouseau) and it is the official method to do full-text search as informed on CouchDB doc site (https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/search.html#install-search).